# Function prototypes

Tags: javascript

I have a function called `Observable`. As per all functions, I can call certain methods on the function, that even though they do not exist directly on the function, JS moves 'down the prototypical chain' and gets the method on the function. Example of such methods is '`toString()`'

```
function Observable(forEachy) {
  this._forEachy = forEachy;
}
console.log(Observable.toString()) // "function Observable(forEach) {this._forEach = forEach;}"
```

Now, when I set `Observable.prototype` to a new object and define some methods in that object, and call those methods on `Observable`, it throws an error.

```
Observable.prototype = {
  forEachy: function (onNext) {
    return onNext();
  }
}
    console.log(Observable.forEachy(()=>"Hi, John")) // error: Observable.forEachy is not a function
```

But I can call those methods on the prototype and it works just fine.

```
console.log(Observable.prototype.forEachy(()=>"Hi, John")); // "Hi, John"
```

Setting a new instance to Observable just works fine.

```
const abc = new Observable("HI");

console.log(abc.forEachy(()=>"Hello world")); // "Hello world"
```

Please, why is that?

Also, apart from passing in the argument received in the constructor to the newly created object, what else does the statement `this._forEachy = forEachy` do?

```
const abc = new Observable("HI");
console.log(abc._forEachy) // "HI"
```

Comment: `Observable.prototype= Object.prototype; Observable.prototype.forEachy = (func)=>func(); console.log(Observable.forEach(()=>"Hi, Jane"))` <--  This doesn't work either.

Comment: (1) `forEachy` is not the same as `forEach` (2) `.forEachy` **is not a direct member of `Observable`**. It is a member of Observable's prototype. (3) Whoever instantiates from Observable will get all inherit from it's prototype indeed.

Comment: @Adelin No, that's absolutely **not** the "correct usage". If you do that you will be adding new prototype methods to ___all objects___.

Comment: @AlfMoh The prototype determines what methods/properties are available on _instances_ of a type (created using `new MyType()`. Changing the prototype does not add new properties to `MyType`.

Comment: @JLRishe thanks - i was citing the wrong source :)

Comment: @JLRishe I'm getting what you are saying. Please can you write an answer and include code so that everything will be much clearer

Answer (score 1):

Your example works as expected. You should consider getting more information about Prototypes in JavaScript.

When you declare something as `Function.prototype = function(){}`, it works similar to methods in OOP programming. In oop you can't call Class.method(), can you? You have to first create an instance to call this method. However, keep in mind that there is a lot of differences between OOP and prototype inheritance. In reality, your "prototype" is not the abstraction. It's the existing object :)

Though, if you want to follow this way, you can create `class` and define `static method`:

```
class Observable {
  static forEachy(){
    // your code here
  }
}
```

and then:

```
Observable.forEachy()
```